# Variance of Multivariate KDE

Tags: variance, kernel-smoothing

I am struggling for 2 hours now and decided to give up. I want to compute the variance of the KDE $$\hat f_H(x) = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\det(H^{-1})K(H^{-1}(x - X_i)).$$
My steps:

I got to the point where

$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n\det(H)^2}\mathbb E[K(H^{-1}(x - X_i))^2] &= ... \\
&= ...\\
&= \frac{1}{n\det(H)^2}\int K(u)^2f(x+Hu)\:\mathrm du.\end{align*}$$
A first order Taylor approximation of $f(x + Hu)$ yields (?) $$f(x + Hu) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)'Hu + O(\Vert Hu\Vert^2)$$
but then I got stuck because I cant get rid of the big oh (I tried its definition and definition of $\Vert\cdot\Vert$: $\mathrm{trace}(\int K(u)^2 uu'\:\mathrm du)H'H $ but the term in the trace may not exist. I just have assumptions about $\int K(u)uu'\:\mathrm du = \nu I$ and $\int K(u)^2\:\mathrm du = R(K)$.)

I also have $$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n\det(H)^2}\mathbb E[K(H^{-1}(x - X_i))]^2 &= ... \\
&= ... \\
&= f(x)^2 + f(x)O(\Vert H\Vert^2) + O(\Vert H\Vert^2)^2 \\
&= f(x) + O(\Vert H\Vert^2)\end{align*}$$
(which is hopefully correct). According to this page https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kde-ii-asymp.html the result should be $$\frac{R(K)}{n\det(H)}f(x) + o\left(\frac{1}{n\det(H)}\right).$$ Note that the page defines $H$ slightly different but that should be neglible.

Comment: In noticed in the second order Taylor Approximation for the univariate case (https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kde-i-asymp.html#thm:kdebiasvar) it is $o$ not $O$. Are you sure it should be $O$?

Also by assumption 51. of (https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/kde-ii-asymp.html) I think $\nabla^2$ is bounded?

Comment: well, I tried to adapt the steps from the univariate case. I don't think $\nabla^2 f$ is bounded (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/continuous-unbounded-but-integrable-functions). Regarding $o$ and $O$. AFAIK there are two ways to state the taylor approximation: 1. $f(x) = f(a) + (x - a)'\nabla f(x) + \color{red}{0.5(x - a)'\nabla^2f(x)(x - a)} + \color{red}o(\Vert x - a\Vert^{\color{red}2})$, 2. $f(x) = f(a) + (x - a)'\nabla f(x) + \color{red}O(\Vert x - a\Vert^{\color{red} 2})$ (se https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3413546/273275)